# What's the Lebesgue Measure of the set of natural numbers?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm having trouble calculating the Lebesgue Measure of $\mathbb{N}$.

I'm starting out with trying to rewrite the set of natural numbers by:
$$\bigcup_{x\in \mathbb{N}} \{ x \}=\mathbb{N}$$

My idea with the notation is:

$$\lambda(\mathbb{N})=\lambda\left(\bigcup_{x\in \mathbb{N}} \{ x \}\right) \stackrel{\text{$x$'s disjoint}}{=} \sum_{x\in \mathbb{N}} \lambda(\{x\})\stackrel{\text{singletons} = 0}{=}0$$

I don't think my procedure is robust enough.

Any hints?

Comment: It is fine, except that before the last equation there are too many $\lambda$s. The outer-most $\lambda$ shouldn't be there.

Comment: Sometimes it's that easy.

Comment: "Too Many Lambdas" is the perfect title for a kid's book about formal logic that I wish I'd had growing up.

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly valid, especially if you're given that the Lebesgue measure is additive over disjoint sets and that singletons have Lebesgue measure zero.

If you're not convinced, here's an alternative proof.

Take $\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\l}{\lambda}
\ve > 0$. To each $n \in \N$, define a ball $B(n;\ve/2^n)$, with center $n$ and radius $\ve/2^n$. Of course,
$$
\l(\N) \le \l \left( \bigcup_{n \in \N} B \left( n ; \frac{\ve}{2^n} \right) \right)\le \sum_{n \in \N} \l \left(   B \left( n ; \frac{\ve}{2^n} \right) \right)$$
by the monotonicity and subadditivity properties of measure. Of course, the balls in question are really intervals in $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
 B \left( n ; \frac{\ve}{2^n} \right) 
= \left[ n - \frac{\ve}{2^n} , n + \frac{\ve}{2^n} \right]
$$
so their measure is naturally $\ve/2^{n-1}$ and

$$\l(\N) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ve}{2^{n-1}} = 2 \ve$$

Since $\l(\N) \ge 0$ definitionally, and $\ve$ can be taken arbitrarily small, it follows that $\l(\N)=0$.